# Angular 6 material app only printing first page

Tags: angular, printing, angular-material

I have an angular 6 app using angular material components (version 6). When I try to print it only prints first page (using Google Chrome). An example can be seen on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wep1jg-mhqyzw?file=app%2Fsidenav-responsive-example.html). I have  tried number of media queries e.g. by setting the following styles but it does not make a difference

```
  body,
  html,
 .mainContainer{
  height: auto;
  overflow-y: visible;
  overflow-x: visible;
  }
```

Comment: where is your app module or app.component or how are you getting other material modules in your code?

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) to any third party site.

Answer (score 13):

I ran into a similar issue recently, Not a solution but a work around  which I found after extensive code inspection.

I am using sidenav from angular material library v9.

```
@media print {
  .mat-drawer-container , .mat-drawer-content {
    overflow: visible !important;
  }
}
```

This seems to help and print all the pages.

Comment: This should be marked the correct answer.

Comment: Adding overflow: visible !important; to body did the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that, when your app's content overflows the page, it is *not* the `<body>` tag that becomes scrollable but rather a child of the `<body>` tag.

In order for the browser to handle printing pagination properly, you'll need to update your app's styles so that the `<body>` tag is the thing that scrolls. [This is similar reasoning to why the material docs say you need to use the `fixed` mat-sidenav option on mobile devices.](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview#creating-a-responsive-layout-for-mobile-amp-desktop)

Looking at your example app, I can see that the body tag has a height of 10 pixels. All the written content has `position: absolute` which is throwing the layout off. Update the styling so that the body tag is full height and things should work (and I just tested this in your stackblitz example and can confirm it fixes the problem).

As one solution, simply updating the `sidenav-responsive-example.css` file to remove the `position: absolute` fixes the problem.

```
.example-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

## Update

Actually, your stackblitz example prints fine for me (in Google Chrome) unchanged.